# Binding Directives after Dynamically Creating an Element in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a code that dynamically create elements (the `x` and the `parentDiv`).

```
var x = document.createElement('myTag');
parentDiv.appendChild(x);
```

And I have a directive that looks like this:

```
.directive("myTag", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        template: "<span><img src='something/url/img.png'></img></span>"
    }
})
```

How can I replace the myTag tag into that code in the directive?
I am aware of using $compile so that the code outside of AngularJS can be covered under its scope but I do not know where to put that.

Comment: Where are you creating this element? Outside of angular context? In a controller? In a factory?

Comment: @FealroneAlajas, did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41713370/2545680) help?

Comment: @Maximus hi. yes. sorry i was a bit today but it works like a charm. thanks! :D

Comment: @FealroneAlajas, great, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you should use `compile` before appending your element:

```
var childScope = scope.$new();
var x = document.createElement('myTag');
var compiled = $compile(x)(childScope);
parentDiv.appendChild(compiled);
```

The `$compile` service will fetch the template:

```
<span><img src='something/url/img.png'></img></span>
```

and put it inside the DOM element referenced with `x`.